# Grails with multiple data sources and Hibernate Envers

Tags: grails, datasource, hibernate-envers

I'm running a Grails 2.2.4 application with multiple data sources. One requirement is to provide auditing with Hibernate Envers. I did the following:

- Domain classes are annotated with `org.hibernate.envers.Audited`
- `org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:3.6.10.Final` is in the classpath
- Hibernate event listeners are defined as follows. This should work with all defined data sources.

  ```
  beans {
     auditEventListener(AuditEventListener)
     hibernateEventListeners(HibernateEventListeners) {
        listenerMap = [
          'post-insert': auditEventListener,
          'post-update': auditEventListener,
          'post-delete': auditEventListener,
          'pre-collection-update': auditEventListener,
          'pre-collection-remove': auditEventListener,
          'post-collection-recreate': auditEventListener
        ]
     }
  }
  ```

However, no audit entries are inserted into the revision tables. Has anyone a hint how to fix this? Is this still an issue with the latest Grails version? I could invest the effort to upgrade. Note, I am using just Hibernate Envers. I do not use any Grails plugin. There is a post on [nabble.com](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Hibernate-Envers-with-multiple-datasources-td4633671.html), but this did not work form.

Answer (score -1):

You can use audit log plugin for this. [Audit log plugin in grails](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging)

Also. see the following for multiple datasource [click me](http://stuff4j.blogspot.in/2011/05/grail-making-audit-logging-plugin-to.html)

Or try to use

> [Grails Envers plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/envers)

Comment: The Audit-Logging Plugin 'logs' into a single table. In my setting, I follow Hibernate Envers' approach where each domain object has its own revision table. So that won't work. Grails Envers Plugin does what I expect, but as far as I understand it, it creates revision entries for the primary data source only. To make it work with this limitation, I had to remove the hibernateEventListeners bean mentioned in my original post. I'm fine with it for the time being.